# Why this viewset is instant while this one is very slow

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My first viewset:

```
class BienAll(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FacebookBien.objects.all()
    pagination_class = SmallPagesPagination
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = FacebookBienSerializer(self.queryset.all(), many=True)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(serializer.data)
        return self.get_paginated_response(page)
```

My second viewset:

```
class Test(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = FacebookBien.objects.all()
    pagination_class = SmallPagesPagination
    serializer_class = FacebookBienSerializer
```

My second viewset is instant but my first is slow, i don't understand why.

Comment: please remove the line 'requete = self.queryset.all()` and replace this line `queryset = FacebookBien.objects` with `queryset = FacebookBien.objects.all()`. And then check again.

Comment: It does not change anything, it's still so slow

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its the ordering at which the pagination happens.

In the first one you, serialise all the data, then access it again to paginate a subset of it. I'd hope DRF is clever enough to paginate before fetching all items.

If you want similar results slice the queryset with the number of items your paginator returns before serializing it - but its much better to just use the second version.

Answer (score 0):

according to this reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related

If FacebookBien has an column ManyToMany, you could use this prefetch_related

```
FacebookBien.objects.all().prefetch_related('many_to_many_column')
```